# When there is 'could' in the indirect as complement clause, what meaning does it add?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> “I feared I might be too late.” 
>  “You nearly were, I couldn’t
>   have kept him off the Stone much longer –” 
>  “Not the Stone, boy,
>   you — the effort involved nearly killed you. For one terrible moment
>   there, I was afraid it had. As for the Stone, it has been destroyed.”
>   
>  “Destroyed?” said Harry blankly. “But your friend — Nicolas
>   Flamel —” 
>  “Oh, you know about Nicolas?” said Dumbledore,
>   sounding quite delighted. “You did do the thing properly, didn’t you?
>   Well, Nicolas and I have had a little chat, and agreed it’s all for
>   the best.” 
>  “But that means he and his wife will die, won’t
>   they?” 
>  “They have enough Elixir stored to set their affairs in
>   order and then, yes, they will die.” 
>  Dumbledore smiled at the
>   look of amazement on Harry’s face. 
>  “To one as young as you, I’m
>   sure it seems incredible, but to Nicolas and Perenelle, it really is
>   like going to bed after a very, very long day. After all, to the
>   well-organized mind, death is but the next great adventure. You know,
>   the Stone was really not such a wonderful thing. **As much money and
>   life as you could want**! The two things most human beings would
>   choose above all — the trouble is, humans do have a knack of choosing
>   precisely those things that are worst for them.”
>  (Harry Potter
>   and the Sorcerer's Stone)

When there is ‘could’ after the conjunction ‘as’, what meaning does it add? I mean, what is the difference from ‘as much money and life as you want’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As much money as you want" means "as much money as you want now" - since it's the present tense. "As much money as you could want" is conditional (I think) and it means "as much money as you might ever want"

Comment: I would say "as much money as you could want" means "as much money as you are capable of wanting".

Comment: _Could_ is usually the past tense of _can_, and since this sentence is past tense (as indicated by the _was_ in the previous phrase) I take it to mean the past tense of "As much money and life as you can want!" This is in agreement with @DavidSchwartz, just a slight paraphrase.